# unresolved external error (d3d)

Tags: direct3d, unresolved-external, d3dx

When ever I try to execute this code

```
D3DXCreateFont(d3dDevice, 20, 0, FW_BOLD, 0, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET,
    OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE,
    choiceFont, &Font);
```

I get this error

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3DXCreateFontA@48 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall BlackBox::CreateFontA(struct IDirect3DDevice9 *,char const *)" (?CreateFontA@BlackBox@@QAEXPAUIDirect3DDevice9@@PBD@Z)    D:\Projects\Black_Box\Black_Box\BlackBox.obj    Black_Box
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to link with `d3dx9.lib` in the legacy DirectX SDK to get D3DXCreateFont. This is noted on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172773.aspx).

If you have this library listed in your inputs, then perhaps your problem is that you have the link library paths incorrectly configured. For VS 2010, 2012, 2013, or 2015 you have to manually add the legacy DirectX SDK paths to your project (VC++ Directories):

For VS 2010 using the Windows 7.x SDK or the "Windows XP compatible" Platform Toolset for VS 2012/2013/2015, you'd list the DirectX SDK paths first--see [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/26/visual-studio-2012-update-1.aspx) for details.

- Win32 / x86 (32-bit)

  - `$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86;$(ExecutablePath)`
  - `$(DXSDK_DIR)Include;$(IncludePath)`
  - `$(DXSDK_DIR)Include;$(IncludePath)`
- x64 native

  - `$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x64;$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86;$(ExecutablePath)`
  - `$(DXSDK_DIR)Include;$(IncludePath)`
  - `$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x64;$(LibraryPath)`

For VS 2012, 2013, 2015 or VS 2010 using Windows 8.x SDK via [props](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/10/18/visual-studio-2013-and-windows-8-1-sdk-rtm-are-now-available.aspx), you list the DirectX SDK paths second--see [Where is the DirectX SDK?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) for details.

- Win32 / x86 (32-bit)

  - `$(ExecutablePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86`
  - `$(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include`
  - `$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86`
- x64 native

  - `$(ExecutablePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x64;$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86`
  - `$(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include`
  - `$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x64`

Comment: Of course, a better solution is to not use legacy Direct3D 9, deprecated D3DX9, or the legacy DirectX SDK. Instead use Direct3D 11 with the Windows SDK built into VS 2012/2013/2015 with the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) library and the ``SpriteFont`` class.

Comment: ``d3dx9.lib`` is a real library. ``d3d9x9.lib`` is not.